# Objective-C: Assigning one CGPoint to another not working

Tags: objective-c, cgpoint

I'm trying to do something extremely simple.

```
CGPoint newPlayerCoordinate = self.thePlayer.playerCoordinate;
newPlayerCoordinate.x = newPlayerCoordinate.x + 1;
self.thePlayer.playerCoordinate = newPlayerCoordinate;
```

The code compiles, however `NSLog` statements are telling me that "`self.thePlayer.playerCoordinate`" is never properly updating, even though I'm setting it equal to a modified `CGPoint`.

I know that "`newPlayerCoordinate`" is updating correctly, also through the use of `NSLog statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated based on revised code in question and comments. Keeping the answer to keep the comments alive.

The most likely problem is that `self.thePlayer` is `nil`. You need to assign a value to the `thePlayer` property.

Comment: Thank you. I messed up when typing my original question. The second line of code should have said: `"newPlayerCoordinate.x = newPlayerCoordinate.x + 1" NOT "newPlayerCoordinate = newPlayerCoordinate.x + 1"` as it did originally. I know this changes your answer now...

Comment: Yes, that's a HUGE difference. Read the last line of my answer. Have you verified that yet?

Comment: Thanks. I did a test and it seems my self.thePlayer is actually nil! I don't understand why though. In my associated header file I have included the object as a property: `@property (strong, nonatomic) PAplayerClass *thePlayer;` I'm probably missing something fundamental here, as I am very new to this.

Comment: You need to assign a value to the `thePlayer` property.

Comment: Good lord. I never allocated memory for the object. I thought because I had defined it as a property in the necessary header file, I was good to go. Long road ahead...You pointed me in the right direction for checking if `self.thePlayer` was nil. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you're assigning a CGFloat to a CGPoint:

```
newPlayerCoordinate = newPlayerCoordinate.x + 1;
```

Use this instead:

```
newPlayerCoordinate = CGPointMake(newPlayerCoordinate.x + 1, newPlayerCoordinate.y);
```

Comment: Thank you. I messed up when typing my original question. The second line of code should have said: `"newPlayerCoordinate.x = newPlayerCoordinate.x + 1" NOT "newPlayerCoordinate = newPlayerCoordinate.x + 1"` as it did originally. I know this changes your answer now...